# Is this company's claim to have solved MITM attacks true?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle

The [Daily Mail reported in Dec 2014](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2885677/Online-privacy-breakthrough-British-researchers-claim-developed-way-internet-security-layer.html) about a company that claimed to have solved the MITM attack.

Can someone explain how this is possible or what the difference is from TLS?

Comment: Not only does that article have a lot of words that don't describe what it actually is/does, when you see words like 'guarantee' and 'foolproof' thrown around in relation to brand new security tech, you can pretty much immediately discount it as ridiculous spin.

Comment: People always downvote without giving a reason

Answer (score 3):

TL;TR: there is maybe (or maybe not) some substance to the patent but I consider the claims made in the press widely exaggerated.  I don't see any substance for the claims of helping against MITM. And it addresses different use cases than TLS, so no need to compare.

While there was [lots of press end of 2014](https://www.google.de/search?q=paran+chandrasekaran+scentrics) about this issue it basically repeats the same fuzzy claims ("privacy", "could have prevented attacks at sony") without getting into any detail.

The patent which they probably refer to is probably [System and method of enforcing a computer policy](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130159704) (or similar patents in other countries). Looking at the claims of this patent basically describes the use of a TPM in the client and a centralized server to secure encryption and decryption at the client, i.e. use remote attestation to make sure that only the correct client gets the keys and use TPM to help with encryption/decryption so that the keys itself will not be available in plain for the clients applications.

So yes, it could have probably helped Sony to encrypt its data a bit but I cannot see how it would have prevented theft of the data once the client has access to the data (needs it to work with them) and the attacker is on the client too. And I completely fail to understand how this could help in privacy as claimed in the press. And the only thing it has to do with MITM is probably to make sure that the exchange between the policy server and the client is protected, but it is nothing to do with MITM of the connection between a client and some web server.

So why did we get such unspecific and exaggerated coverage by the press? It might be that the company needs to show its investors that it has good assets because the finances itself [don't look that good](https://www.endole.co.uk/company/06539484/scentrics-information-security-technologies-limited?). And it is very strange then I could not even find an official web site for this company.